# error while displaying multiline data in ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

i am displaying content in ckeditor textarea from the database.
my content is stored in content variable and it is multiline.

code:

```
editor.setData(' < ?php 
echo  nl2br($content); ?>');
```

it gives error unterminated string literal!

**EDITED:**

code posted in comment:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var editor; 
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) { 
  editor = ev.editor; 
}); 
$('#custype').click(function(){ 
  editor.setData('<?php echo $content;?>'); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this

```
var taxt_content = '<?php echo nl2br($content);?>';
editor.setData(taxt_content);
```

Comment: @DeepGandhi : please check $content php variable. May be its return null value.

Comment: unterminated string literal

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have leave a space between < and ?php that's why it is giving you error.

Use this:

```
editor.setData('<?php echo nl2br($content);?>');
```

Comment: @DeepGandhi try by removing the `nl2br` function.

Comment: @DeepGandhi *Always* copy and paste your actual code into the question.

Comment: @DeepGandhi can you post more code. I think you are calling it in the JS.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var editor;
// The instanceReady event is fired, when an instance of CKEditor has finished
// its initialization.
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
    editor = ev.editor;
 
});
$('#custype').click(function(){ 
 editor.setData('<?php echo $content;?>');
 
});

Answer (score 0):

My solution is here:

```
var test = '<?php echo trim($girl['andesc_Content_Cs']); ?>';
CKEDITOR.instances.inputTextareaOne.setData(test);
```

php function trim is BEST !!!